# SQL revising table data to a more compact form

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with data pairs modeled like the following:

```
Id1    Id2
-----------
100    50
120    70
70     50
34     20
50     40
40     10
```

`Id1` is always bigger then `Id2`. The pairs represent replacements to be made. So 100 will be replaced with 50, but then 50 will be replaced with 40, which will then be replaced by 10.

So the result would be like this:

```
Id1    Id2
-----------
100    10
120    10
34     20
```

Is there a nice succinct way that I can alter, or join this table to represent this?

I know i can join it on itself something akin to:

```
SELECT t1.Id1, t2.Id2
  FROM mytable t1
  JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.Id1 = t1.Id2
```

But this will require several passes, hence why i ask if there is a nicer way to accomplish it?

Comment: provided heirarchy is not 'too' deep, you could use a heirarchical CTE

Comment: Oracle has 'connect by prior' functionality. Maybe sql-server has something similar?

Comment: Not familiar with either of these so just having a google now

Comment: @OMGPonies have edited the above to make it a bit more clear, i want to go from two pairs (100,90) and (90,80) to one pair (100,80). But possibly over several iterations etc

Comment: Still don't understand -- shouldn't there only be one entry for 120, 10?

Comment: How do you mean one entry? Maybe don't think of it as numbers. If you have a Bike, then you have a wheel. If you have a wheel then you have a tire. I want take the data (bike has wheel) and (wheel has tire) and jump to (bike has tire). This can also  mean (car has wheel), (wheel has tire), so (car has tire). These would stay seperate in the data as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @t table(Id1 int, Id2 int)
insert @t values (100, 50)
insert @t values (    120,    70)
insert @t values (    70,     50)
insert @t values (    34,     20)
insert @t values (    50,     40)
insert @t values (    40,     10)

;with a as
(
-- find all rows without parent <*>
select id2, id1 from @t t where not exists (select 1 from @t where t.id1 = id2)
union all -- recusive work down to lowest child while storing the parent id1 
select t.id2 , a.id1
from a
join @t t on a.id2 = t.id1
)
-- show the lowest child for each row found in <*>
select id1, min(id2) id2 from a
group by id1
```

Result:

```
id1         id2
----------- -----------
34          20
100         10
120         10
```

Comment: Are you able to explain a bit more how the query works after the 'union all' part. Is it recursive?

Comment: @dann.dev yes, it is recursive. I added some comments that should make the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't end up doing this as there wasn't actually that many cases where it would have whittled the data down but it does what I needed!