# SQL - What order does update work on a table, is it guaranteed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I've looked around and can not seem to find the answer to this, but feel free to point me straight to it if I have blatantly overlooked it.

I have a query that updates a table. The update is dependent on the order of the table.

Do SQL update statements work straight down through a table, row by row? Does the Update statement look at each row direct from the table, or from a 'cached select' of the table preformed at the start. I have data that kind of cascades down the table, and I'm not sure that it will work correctly.

Secondly, to do this Update, i use an `Update` - `From` statement, where the table is joined to another, then back on itself. Will an `order by` statement order the data before the Update takes place, or do something else?

I am using SQL server 2008 r2.

UPDATE: This is relation to another question that i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764915/sql-revising-table-data-to-a-more-compact-form).
The update works on Data that looks like:

```
Id1    Id2
-----------
100    50
120    70
70     50
34     20
50     40
40     10
```

And should overall, update information from Id1, to Id2 so the above will make updates that effectively update on the following data, which is a reduction of the above:

```
Id1    Id2
-----------
100    10
120    10
34     20
```

I had looked at it and assumed, 'hey, if it works from top to bottom in desc, there's no need to worry about doing this as the updates will happen in order anyone and carry through. But obviously that's not correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the order of the table*"

Comment: Indeed, I do know that (after you reminded me!), I guess what I'm asking is can i guarantee an order of some kind for the update to take place?

Comment: Could you not use the Execution Plan in SQL Management Studio to see how the the query will be executed and in what order?

Comment: The order the rows are physically updated in shouldn't usually matter. If you are trying to do something that relies on the post update version of the row then chances are it won't work. SQL Server will use the pre-update version of the row. The one exception where it can make a difference is using the "quirky update" technique. Jeff Moden has a list of preconditions [which he asserts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) will guarantee the update is carried out in clustered index key order.

Comment: 'cascades down the table' how?  I'd be a little leery of any applications that required that type of behaviour, especially if you _ever_ want to perform processing in a multi-threaded environment.  Usually, you're going to want to use OLAP functions for this...

Comment: I agree with X-Zero: the problem sounds like you want OLAP (windowing) functions somewhere in your statement.

Comment: Have updated the question with a bit more background info, I realise I have a solution for making the change to the data and am now wondering if it can be done with out it. I'll have a look at OLAP too

Comment: Your initial result set has 6 rows. The final 3. `UPDATE` doesn't delete any rows.

Comment: Sorry, the update works on that data, so I want to update information from Id1 to Id2, So set something on '10', according to what was on '100'> I was hoping the update could go 100>50, then 50>40, then 40>10. This is what i meant by cascading down. Obviously i have not explained this well!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "There is no such thing as *the order of the table*" -- sure there is: `SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY c;` and the result is called a table (although not all table expressions are permitted to have an `ORDER BY` clause). It's one of the 'features' of SQL that sets it apart from the relational model. There is no such thing as "the order of the *relation*"

Comment: @onedaywhen: I agree. I should have written "there is no such thing as the order of a table **without using ORDER BY**"

Comment: @onedaywhen - Isn't an ordered resultset called a `cursor` in ANSI SQL? That's what Itzik Ben Gan says anyway in book Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 T-SQL Fundamentals "A query with an ORDER BY clause results in what ANSI calls a cursor—a nonrelational result with order guaranteed among rows."

Comment: @MartinSmith: I don't know, I can't see the wood for the trees :) Looking at the old SQL-92 spec there are 100 instances of the phrase "declare cursor" and over 500 instances of the word "cursor". Regardless, calling it a cursor makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed you are all right, my issue though, is once you have an table with `order by`, will an update adhere to that order, or is it considered a new operation with no order?! It seems a cursor is definitely the answer either way though

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update in a specific order, use a cursor:

```
declare myCursor cursor
for select * from myTable1 t1
inner join myTable2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fid
order by t1.id  /* <==== */
for update of t1.col1, t1.col2

open myCursor
fetch next from myCursor /* optional into clause */
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    update myCursor set col1 = /* Some expression */, col2 = /* Some expression */
    fetch next from myCursor  /* optional into clause */
end
close myCursor 
deallocate myCursor
```

Comment: Does this have much of a performance hit when scaling? I'm looking at about 3mil rows, well indexed, on a good server, so not so much of issue, hopefully